# Jenkins hanging in the step "is-inside-work-tree"

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I configure the Jenkins job like this:

> [image: configure]

the credentials are valid. However I get the result:

> [image: result]

and it hangs there forever.

Comment: And Sometimes, Jenkins will hang on cloning the repo:
`Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@github.com:acl-services/data-access.git
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe init C:\Work\automation # timeout=10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved by removing the Jenkins workspace

There is a setting in the Jenkins job config:
[image]

Assumption: the Jenkins workspace creates some hiccup occasionally. I stay a little bit more conscious on delegating the workspace. If we delete the workspace, it means we have to reinstall all the dependencies in automation. Sometimes, it may be time consuming.

The root cause of this issue is still unknown.
Manually remove the directory may not work.